# How can i merge 2 objects in blender?

Tags: graphics, 3d, blender

I have 2 objects. I cut the head off the model and I want to add Einstein's head, but models are animated before. When the animation works, head and body is separating. I am using blender.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can merge objects using Ctrl+J or searching "Join" in the "Space" key menu. After that, you can enter in Edit Mode, and manualy connect rthe neck and the head, or use "Bridge Loops"

But all the non-active objects will be "assimilated" into the active one, the new object will have the active objects name, animations and many other properties. So the joined objects will lost their own animations, and the head will move together with the body.

If you want to keep them together, but also move the head, you may parent the head to the body, and modify the head's animation to avoid separation, or use an armature.